# Проверьте правильность составления схем и правильность расстановки знаком препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Проверьте правильность составления схем и правильность расстановки знаком препинания
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Требуется **исправление**:

7) Дрова собирать сейчас поздно, они **к тому же** сырые.  В качестве варианта разбора: Это ССП, К ТОМУ ЖЕ  ― присоединительный союз.

Сказуемое ― поздно собирать, дрова ― дополнение. Односоставное безличное предложение. Составное глагольное сказуемое, в качестве вспомогательной части наречие "поздно" (в прошедшем времени такое наречие имеет связку было: было поздно).

10)  Больше было на воде листьев кувшинок. Подлежащее ― больше листьев и  кувшинок, сказуемое ― было.

Comment: Почему слова "узкий и мелкий" не выделены с помощью запятых или тире . Один, узкий и мелкий, край озера совсем зарос. Какой именно край? Узкий и мелкий. Означает ли отсуствие запятых, что   по меньшей мере два края были узкими и мелкими?

Comment: Здесь скорее пояснительные отношения, определение надо обособить. При этом лучше изменить позицию, так читается и понимается проще: Один край озера, узкий и мелкий,  совсем зарос.

Comment: В оригинале нет обособления. Это ошибка или есть этому объяснение? "Озеро стало меньше и постарело  как будто... Один узкий  и мелкий конец
его совсем зарос осокой и камышом; сильнее  разрослись  и наклонились к воде
деревья, больше было на темной воде листьев кувшинок." (http://www.lib.ru/PROZA/KAZAKOW/r_na_ohote.txt)

Comment: Это не ошибка, значит, здесь неоднородные отношения. Слово "один" многозначное, одно из значений по словарю -  только тот, который указан.   Смысл такой: один конец озера точно зарос, а о других речи нет (может быть, есть еще заросшие). Вот похожий пример: Я знаю один недорогой и уютный  ресторанчик.